# MySQL join two tables without NOT IN

Tags: mysql

Two tables `users`, `relationships` in my db.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id int primary key auto_increment,
nickname varchar(20),
is_active TINYINT
)

CREATE TABLE relationships(
id int primary key auto_increment,
user_id int,
target_user_id int,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
FOREIGN KEY(target_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
)
```

```
mysql> select * from users;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | nickname | is_active |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 | hide     |         1 |
|  2 | john     |         1 |
|  3 | ben      |         0 |
|  4 | test     |         1 |
|  5 | gogo     |         1 |
+----+----------+-----------+

mysql> select * from relationships;
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | user_id | target_user_id |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 |       1 |              2 |
|  2 |       1 |              4 |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

I have to extract `users.id` with certain condition.

I will explain in case of `users.id = 1`

1. `users.is_active=1`
2. user who does not have relationships via `relationships` table. you know that in current `relationships` table, `user_id = 1` has 2 rows that `target_user_id = 2 and 4`. So query result does not contain `user_id = 2 and 4`.

Using `NOT IN`, it is pretty simple.

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE is_active=1 AND id NOT IN(SELECT target_user_id FROM relationships WHERE user_id=1)

RESULT : 1, 5
```

Note that there is huge rows in `users` and `relationships`.

If I using NOT IN with subquery, it will occur performance issue.

So I think I have to join with foreign key but I don't know how to make query exactly.

Any suggestion, appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS:** I am sure `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` approach will definitely work for you

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN relationships r ON r.target_user_id = u.id
    AND r.user_id = 1
WHERE u.is_active=1 AND r.target_user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: that would need to be an OUTER join.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to try it first though It's pretty much clear from the query that what the output will be.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your query. MySQL should be able to use your index.

However, you can also use left join:

```
SELECT
    users.id
FROM
    users
    LEFT JOIN relationships ON (
            users.id = relationships.target_user_id
/*
        -- un-comment if filtering by user is needed
        AND relationships.user_id = 1
*/
    )
WHERE
        users.is_active=1
    AND relationships.target_user_id IS NULL
    -- addition filtering can be here
```

UPDATE:
If you filtering by user, you can try to add composite index (user_id, target_user_id) to `relationships` table (columns should be in this order)

Comment: How can I trigger only in case of `users.id = 1`?

Comment: You can add `relationships.user_id = 1` into ON. However, if you filtering by relationships.user_id your query should be fast! Well, you can try to add composite index (user_id, target_user_id) on relationships table.